# how to flatten a seq containing seq of vectors

Tags: clojure

I have a seq in this format -

( ([2 3 4] [7 6 8]) (["hh" 5] [9 8]))

I want to flatten it so that its a seq of vectors instead of a seq of seq of vectors. How do I do that ?

Also flatten completely flattens it, I want to only flatten it one level to - ([2 3 4] [ 7 6 8] ["hh" 5] [9 8])

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `concat`:

```
(apply concat seq)
```

Comment: I am using a map that is returning this result, is there a flatmap or something equivalent ?

Comment: Also flatten completely flattens it, I want to only flatten it one level

Comment: @murtaza52 There is `mapcat`. So `(apply concat (map f coll))` becomes `(mapcat f coll)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
(reduce (fn[h v]
          (reduce (fn[s e] (conj s e)) h v))
        [] [[[2 3 4] [7 6 8]] [["hh" 5] [9 8]]])
```